# Ionic 4 / Angular 7 app *randomly* not rendering parts of a component (android build)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have this app where i show posts, and for some reason, certain parts of the post are not rendered, although the elements that should render are already inside the DOM [image describing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0buN.jpg).

this happens only when i build the app for android.

the real issue is: there is no pattern to reproduce the problem, no errors in console, it just happens randomly when i'm browsing using the next/prev buttons.

i have tried the following:

1. trigger [detectchanges](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges) manually.
2. use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to force hardware acceleration.

but nothing worked

i have never seen this before and i didn't find anything after some searching..
 i'm running out of ideas on how to detect what's the problem or how to fix it, any help is  appreciated, even small suggestions

Comment: can you share your actual code how exactly your button is configured in this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what was the problem but updating the `ionic` version to `4.6.2` solved it.